# Python decorator for optional arguments decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, meta-programming

I want my Python decorators to have optional arguments and not be called when not necessary.

The accepted answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888158/python-making-decorators-with-optional-arguments) doesn't accept named arguments, and I don't want to add boilerplate code inside decorators, so I came up with an alternative decorator:

```
import inspect

def decorator_defaults(**defined_defaults):
    def decorator(f):
        args_names = inspect.getargspec(f)[0]

        def wrapper(*new_args, **new_kwargs):
            defaults = dict(defined_defaults, **new_kwargs)
            if len(new_args) == 0:
                return f(**defaults)
            elif len(new_args) == 1 and callable(new_args[0]):
                return f(**defaults)(new_args[0])
            else:
                too_many_args = False
                if len(new_args) > len(args_names):
                    too_many_args = True
                else:
                    for i in range(len(new_args)):
                        arg = new_args[i]
                        arg_name = args_names[i]
                        defaults[arg_name] = arg
                if len(defaults) > len(args_names):
                    too_many_args = True
                if not too_many_args:
                    final_defaults = []
                    for name in args_names:
                        final_defaults.append(defaults[name])
                    return f(*final_defaults)
                if too_many_args:
                    raise TypeError("{0}() takes {1} argument(s) "
                                    "but {2} were given".
                                    format(f.__name__,
                                           len(args_names),
                                           len(defaults)))
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Two sample decorators:

```
from functools import wraps

@decorator_defaults(start_val="-=[", end_val="]=-")
def my_text_decorator(start_val, end_val):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return "".join([f.__name__, ' ', start_val,
                            f(*args, **kwargs), end_val])
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@decorator_defaults(end_val="]=-")
def my_text_decorator2(start_val, end_val):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return "".join([f.__name__, ' ', start_val,
                            f(*args, **kwargs), end_val])
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And usage of sample text decorators:

```
@my_text_decorator
def func1a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator()
def func2a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("-=[")
def func2b(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator(end_val=" ...")
def func3a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("-=[", end_val=" ...")
def func3b(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator("|> ", " <|")
def func4a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("|> ", " <|")
def func4b(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator(end_val=" ...", start_val="|> ")
def func5a(value):
    return value


@my_text_decorator2("|> ", end_val=" ...")
def func5b(value):
    return value


print(func1a('My sample text'))  # func1a -=[My sample text]=-
print(func2a('My sample text'))  # func2a -=[My sample text]=-
print(func2b('My sample text'))  # func2b -=[My sample text]=-
print(func3a('My sample text'))  # func3a -=[My sample text ...
print(func3b('My sample text'))  # func3b -=[My sample text ...
print(func4a('My sample text'))  # func4a |> My sample text <|
print(func4b('My sample text'))  # func4b |> My sample text <|
print(func5a('My sample text'))  # func5a |> My sample text ...
print(func5b('My sample text'))  # func5b |> My sample text ...
```

`decorator_defaults` works, but I believe it could be written better.
I'm not that experienced in Python, so I would like to hear some ideas/comments on how to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks rather complicated. Instead of trying to understand it, I'd just like to point to [NickC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966822/222914) to the linked SO question.

If I add `**kwargs` to his `optional_arg_decorator` like this...

```
def optional_arg_decorator(fn):
    def wrapped_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and len(kwargs) == 0 and callable(args[0]):
            return fn(args[0])

        else:
            def real_decorator(decoratee):
                return fn(decoratee, *args, **kwargs)

            return real_decorator

    return wrapped_decorator
```

...and adapt your decorators like this, I'm getting the same output from the test cases.

```
from functools import wraps

@optional_arg_decorator
def my_text_decorator(f, start_val="-=[", end_val="]=-"):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return "".join([f.__name__, ' ', start_val,
                        f(*args, **kwargs), end_val])
    return wrapper

@optional_arg_decorator
def my_text_decorator2(f, start_val, end_val="]=-"):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return "".join([f.__name__, ' ', start_val,
                        f(*args, **kwargs), end_val])
    return wrapper
```

Comment: The [`wrapt.decorator`](https://codewithoutrules.com/2017/08/10/python-decorators/) is like `@wraps` but supports python 2.7 as well.